# Error when I run my C# program that work's with Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle10g

I Made Setup from my C# program (that work's with Oracle 10g)

when I try to run this program - in different Computer, i got this error message:

unable to load dll 'OraOps10.dll'

what it can be ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the Oracle ODP (`Oracle.DataAccess.Client`) and not the default Microsoft ODP (`System.Data.OracleClient`) then you have to download install the [Oracle Data Access Compontents](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) before you can use it. So installing the ODAC must be the part of your deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, just maybe, oracle isn't installed on this 'different Computer'?

Answer (score 0):

Either Oracle is not installed or the oracle dll can't be found for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I've came across this and various Oracle errors before. It is usually an authorization issue, provided that of course, Oracle is installed and configured correctly.

Locate the 'ORACLE_HOME' folder, right click and set the security settings. Make sure the SYSTEM account has permission to Read & Execute the files in the folders and all subfolders and files. If you're accessing Oracle from a web application, do this for the ASP.NET user.

For more information see also: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=67364